# CSS animation in MS Edge and IE animates in wrong direction

Tags: css, internet-explorer, animation, css-animations, microsoft-edge

I have created a simple css animation that translates an pseudo element vertically. This animation works great in Chrome, FireFox and Safari but not so much in Microsoft Edge or Internet Explorer.

I am struggling to figure out the reason for this bug. Any help would be great!

**How the animation should look:**

[image: How the animation should look]

**How it looks in Edge and IE:**

[image: How the animation looks in Edge and IE]

**Animation example:** https://jsfiddle.net/9x5vckhb/

```
@keyframes scroll {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-50%, 20%);
        opacity: 0;
    },
    30% {
        opacity: 1;
    },
    40% {
        opacity: 1;
    },
    70% {
        transform: translate(-50%, 120%);
        opacity: 0;
    },
    100% {
        transform: translate(-50%, 120%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am wondering if this is a bug or not. I for the life could not wrap my head around this. It seemed like the x & y were being swapped after the first animation loop. Switched to `transform3d()` and it worked perfectly.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9x5vckhb/2/)

```
&:before {
    content: '•';
    font-size: round($width/100*63.3);
    top: 0;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 30%, 0);
    animation: scroll ease 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
```

And

```
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 20%, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  },
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
  },
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
  },
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 120%, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  },
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 120%, 0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Switching to `transform3d()` worked perfectly. Must be a random bug. Thank you.